# Get the only record from DynamoDB single record table

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table which will have one record.
It will be updated periodically but the table will only ever have one record with 4 fields.

Is there a way to get that one record without specifying a primary key and without using scan as it is costly? See below.

```
{
count: "1",
startDate:"2024-01-30",
endDate:"2024-01-30",
completed: "yes"    
}

public State getState(String count) {
    return dynamoDBMapper.load(State.class, count);
}
```

The count field is the primary key as in `--key-schema '[{"AttributeName": "count", "KeyType": "HASH"}]'`

You see, don't want to hardcode the count=1 in my code or put it in an external file.
I am not sure if its possible to just go in and grab the only item in the table without a key, may be a get all approach. Any ideas?

Comment: You can scan the table. It will return all items, which is this case is one item.

Comment: You may want to update this code to Enhanced Client which is V2. V1 is on Road to Deprecation and AWS recommends moving to V2.  See -- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-end-of-support-for-aws-sdk-for-java-v1-x-on-december-31-2025/

Answer (score 2):

For a table with a single item, all you need to do is `Scan` and it will return that single item.

It will have the same cost and performance as a `GetItem` as there's only a single item to evaluate.

```
mapper.scan(State.class,{})
```